# Getting CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. on a Django forms on live server

Tags: python, django, nginx

Hello I am learning Django i write a app and publish it in AWS EC2 instance with gunicorn and ngnix
on local environments everything works fine but in production on every submit on forms i get this 403 Error :

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

More information is available with DEBUG=True.
```

iam sure in templates every form have {% csrf_token %} and this is my setting.py file of django app:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from decouple import config

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = config("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")

SITE_ID = 1

DEBUG = False


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["winni-furnace.ca", "www.winni-furnace.ca"]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.winni-furnace.ca'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    # local
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'mail_service.apps.MailServiceConfig',
    'messages_app.apps.MessagesAppConfig',
    'offers.apps.OffersConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'projects.apps.ProjectsConfig',
    'score.apps.ScoreConfig',
    'services.apps.ServicesConfig',
    # 3rd
    'taggit',
    "django_social_share",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    # ...
    "127.0.0.1",
    # ...
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.CustomUser"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "pages:index"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "pages:index"

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config('POSTGRES_DB'),
        'USER': config('POSTGRES_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'wiinidb.cxmwqowm20bd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django_ses.SESBackend"
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = "us-west-1"
ASW_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = "email-smtp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "info@winni-furnace.ca"

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'wiini'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_NAME = config("AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_NAME")
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ca-central-1'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_VERITY = True
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

this is my ngnix config :

```
server{

        listen 80;
        server_name  winni-furnace.ca www.winni-furnace.ca;

        location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/winnipeg_prod/app/staticfiles;
    }

        location / {

                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/winnipeg_prod/app/app.sock;
           
        }

}
```

i dont have idea what i must do and why this happen and also iam not professional so if i do a silly misstake take it easy on me thank you

update ( I turn debug to True ) i get this error page now :

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help
Reason given for failure:

    Origin checking failed - https://winni-furnace.ca does not match any trusted origins.
    
In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’s CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function passes a request to the template’s render method.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.
You’re seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.

You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

Comment: Can you post some views and templates that gives this error.

Comment: @PouryaMohamadi In your nginx config you are listening to port 80 but you are hitting your site url with https which is port 443. Try with just http see if that works. If it works then you need to add 443 listener too for https in nginx.

Comment: @Ahtisham thats my problem i try to set that config but i get so many errors

Comment: Does it work if you hit your website with http rather than https ? If yes what issue you get for https ? Have you wrote the configuration for https ?

Comment: @Ahtisham ssl fixing my preoblem thank you so much

Comment: @Ahtisham sorry i was busy thank you again its done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works fine but in production on every submit on forms i get this 403 Error

The reason you get this error is because you are requesting your website with https but you have not defined the 443 port on nginx. Here is a [post](https://realpython.com/django-nginx-gunicorn/) to do this using AWS.

Here is a simple example:

```
server {
     server_name  winni-furnace.ca www.winni-furnace.ca;
     location /static/ {
     root /home/ubuntu/winnipeg_prod/app/staticfiles;
     return 301 https://winni-furnace.ca$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name winni-furnace.ca www.winni-furnace.ca;

    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/of/winni_cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/of/winni.key;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; 
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Notice I have added this line `return 301 https://winni-furnace.ca$request_uri;` which will redirect all http request to https automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in your settings.py

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://domaim.com'
]
```

Comment: Look at this also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70518254/13861187 .